# Most first class century in cricket?

Tags: cricket, statistics, records

Which batsman has scored most first class century in history of cricket?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially answered in the first result of any Google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jack Hobbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Hobbs) scored the highest number of first class centuries in the period of 1905 to 1934, he played for the team Surrey.

He scored [199 centuries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_batsmen_who_have_scored_100_centuries_in_first-class_cricket) in the first class cricket.